# How to fix attribute error in Python NetCat clone?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm new to Python and the socket library, and the book I'm reading is called Black Hat Python. There's an exercise in the book that requires the reader to essentially glue together (or re-write) pieces of code in order to create a Netcat clone. I believe I have successfully done this, as I can run the command "python3 netcat.py --help" without any issues. However, when I try to run the command "python3 netcat.py -t 192.168.0.58 -p 5555 -c -l", I'm given this: AttributeError: 'NetCat' object has no attribute 'run'

How do I fix this?
Here's the code:

```
import argparse
import socket
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
import textwrap
import threading

def execute(cmd):
  cmd = cmd.strip()
  if not cmd:
    return
  output = subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  return output.decode()

class NetCat:
  def __init__(self, args, buffer=None):
    self.args = args
    self.buffer = buffer
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

def run(self):
  if self.args.listen:
    self.listen()
  else:
    self.send()

def send(self):
  self.socket.connect((self.args.target, self.args.port))
  if self.buffer:
    self.socket.send(self.buffer)

  try:
    while True:
      recv_len = 1
      response = ''
      while recv_len:
        data = self.socket.recv(4096)
        recv_len = len(data)
        response += data.decode
        if recv_len < 4096:
          break
      if response:
        print(response)
        buffer = input('>  ')
        buffer += '\n'
        self.socket.send(buffer.encode())
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("User terminated.")
    self.socket.close()
    sys.exit()

def listen(self):
  self.socket.bind((self.args.target, self.args.port))
  self.socket.listen(5)
  while True:
    client_socket, _ = self.socket.accept()
    client_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.handle,args=(client_socket,))
    client_thread.start()

def handle(self, client_socket):
  if self.args.execute:
    output = execute(self.args.execute)
    client_socket.send(output.encode())
  elif self.args.upload:
    file_buffer = b''
    while True:
      data = client_socket.recv(4096)
      if data:
        file_buffer += data
      else:
        break
    with open(self.args.upload, 'wb') as f:
      f.write(file_buffer)
    message = f'Saved file {self.args.upload}'
    client_socket.send(message.encode())
  elif self.args.command:
    cmd_buffer = ''
    while True:
      try:
        client_socket.send(b'BHP: #> ')
        while '\n' not in cmd_buffer.decode():
          cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(64)
        response = execute(cmd_buffer.decode())
        if response:
          client_socket.send(response.encode())
        cmd_buffer = b''
      except Exception as e:
        print(f'Server killed {e}')
        self.socket.close()
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Net Tool', formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,epilog=textwrap.dedent('''Example: 
  netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 -l -c # command shell
  netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 -l -u=mytest.txt # upload to file
  netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\" # execute command
  echo 'ABC' | ./netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 135 #  echo text to server port 135
  netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 # connect to server
'''))

parser.add_argument('-c', '--command', action='store_true', help='command shell') 
parser.add_argument('-e', '--execute', help='execute specified command')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--listen', action='store_true', help='listen')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int, default=5555, help='specified port')
parser.add_argument('-t', '--target', default='192.168.1.203', help='specified IP')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--upload', help='upload file')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.listen:
  buffer = ''
else:
  buffer = sys.stdin.read()

nc = NetCat(args, buffer.encode())
nc.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an indentation error. The only method that currently belongs to the class `NetCat` is `__init__`. The methods below it, starting with `run(self)` do not have the same indentation as the `__init__` so they don't "belong" to the class `NetCat`.

Indentation is extremely important in python. It specifies so-called [code blocks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html). If you put the definition for the method `run` on the same indentation level as the method `__init__`, then the method `run` will "belong" to the class `NetCat`.

On a side note, it is standard to indent with 4 spaces in python. I highly advise you to follow this standard ASAP, as habits are easy to learn but hard to break. I suggest to use a proper code editor like Visual Studio Code or even Notepad++ as they *auto-indent* when appropriate.

==============================================
EDIT:

I've indented the code in such a way that it should work. Note the difference in indentation for all the methods starting from `run`. Since they are now in the code block for the class `NetCat`, they "belong" to this class. I cannot overstate how important indentation is in python. It is one of the core concepts of python, and knowing what it does and how it behaves is absolutely necessary if you want to write any code in python.

```py
import argparse
import socket
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys
import textwrap
import threading


def execute(cmd):
    cmd = cmd.strip()
    if not cmd:
        return
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        shlex.split(cmd), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return output.decode()


class NetCat:
    def __init__(self, args, buffer=None):
        self.args = args
        self.buffer = buffer
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)


    def run(self):
        if self.args.listen:
            self.listen()
        else:
            self.send()


    def send(self):
        self.socket.connect((self.args.target, self.args.port))
        if self.buffer:
            self.socket.send(self.buffer)

        try:
            while True:
                recv_len = 1
                response = ''
                while recv_len:
                    data = self.socket.recv(4096)
                    recv_len = len(data)
                    response += data.decode
                    if recv_len < 4096:
                        break
                if response:
                    print(response)
                    buffer = input('>  ')
                    buffer += '\n'
                    self.socket.send(buffer.encode())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("User terminated.")
            self.socket.close()
            sys.exit()


    def listen(self):
        self.socket.bind((self.args.target, self.args.port))
        self.socket.listen(5)
        while True:
            client_socket, _ = self.socket.accept()
            client_thread = threading.Thread(
                target=self.handle, args=(client_socket,))
            client_thread.start()


    def handle(self, client_socket):
        if self.args.execute:
            output = execute(self.args.execute)
            client_socket.send(output.encode())
        elif self.args.upload:
            file_buffer = b''
            while True:
                data = client_socket.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    file_buffer += data
                else:
                    break
            with open(self.args.upload, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(file_buffer)
            message = f'Saved file {self.args.upload}'
            client_socket.send(message.encode())
        elif self.args.command:
            cmd_buffer = ''
            while True:
                try:
                    client_socket.send(b'BHP: #> ')
                    while '\n' not in cmd_buffer.decode():
                        cmd_buffer += client_socket.recv(64)
                    response = execute(cmd_buffer.decode())
                    if response:
                        client_socket.send(response.encode())
                    cmd_buffer = b''
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Server killed {e}')
                    self.socket.close()
                    sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Net Tool', formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, epilog=textwrap.dedent('''Example: 
  netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 -l -c # command shell
  netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 -l -u=mytest.txt # upload to file
  netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 -l -e=\"cat /etc/passwd\" # execute command
  echo 'ABC' | ./netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 135 #  echo text to server port 135
  netcat.py -t 192.168.1.108 -p 5555 # connect to server
'''))

parser.add_argument('-c', '--command', action='store_true',
                    help='command shell')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--execute', help='execute specified command')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--listen', action='store_true', help='listen')
parser.add_argument('-p', '--port', type=int,
                    default=5555, help='specified port')
parser.add_argument(
    '-t', '--target', default='192.168.1.203', help='specified IP')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--upload', help='upload file')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.listen:
    buffer = ''
else:
    buffer = sys.stdin.read()

nc = NetCat(args, buffer.encode())
nc.run()
```

Comment: Thank you! I have VSCode installed and format on save enabled, so I'm surprised that it's just that.

Comment: I have just tried indenting the code, and it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Do you know what else it could be?

Comment: @frostedflakes I've updated my answer. Check if this works for you...